# Changing Web.Config for SSL Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, web-deployment

Hello:

I have a SSL Website with port: 99. In my web.config what and where changes I have to make in order to get through this SSL Port?

This is my Web.Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="Test.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="Ssl"/>
       </security>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The site is showing me this err:

> > The page cannot be displayed  You have attempted to execute a CGI,
> >     ISAPI, or other executable program
> >     from a directory that does not allow
> >
> > ### programs to be executed.
>
> Please try the following:  •Contact
>   the Web site administrator if you
>   believe this directory should allow
>   execute access.   HTTP Error 403.1 -
>   Forbidden: Execute access is denied.
>
> ### Internet Information Services (IIS)

This is how my IIS 6.0 settings looks like:
[image: eHome Directory IIS 6.0 Settings]

Dont know what should be done here? Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an IIS configuration issue. Can you find more information on the infrastructure you're hosting the site on (IIS6 vs IIS7/7.5 etc). The http/https ports are also configured within IIS, which is why you can't find the config items in the Web.Config

Comment: This is an IIS configuration error. You need to grant execute permission to the web application. How you do that depends on what version of IIS you are running, as @Tr1stan said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an image](http://www.barcodetools.com/images/barcode/barcode_cgi/barcode_cgi/iis6-cgi-permissions.gif) showing where you grant execute rights in IIS6 within the IIS manager

Comment: I did this, but still the same err. I edited my question with an Image, can you pls have a look at it?

Comment: @klm9971: And you're definitely configuring the correct section of IIS, you're not hosting this particular site inside a Virtual Directory that is a child of the root config you're now showing us?

Comment: @T: Yes! This website is hosted into an external server which has a root and it has a folder inside that root directory....What should I do?

Comment: @klm9971: Try setting the same config (Script Only... or Script and Executables) as you've done for the root, but on the Virtual Directory that is hosting the web app.

Comment: @T: In the home directory the execute permissions is: NONE

Comment: @klm9971: OK, looks like that's your problem - set that to either [Scripts only...] or [Scripts and Executables] (see image link above) > Then OK the dialog.

Comment: @T: If I change that, will it ruin my other sub directories (websites which are running currently)?

Comment: @klm9971: The configuration of each of the Virtual Directories should all be independent, although it is possible that they share application pools. I don't have a copy of IIS6 here to test, but my gut feeling is you should be OK - but as always, if it matters and you're unsure, wait until your "at risk" time to make configuration changes.

Comment: @T: I checked my websites which are under the home, they have their own App pool. But when I am checking my own, my folder is not there in the application pool. I am guessing this might be a reason or what?